# Flutter: How to return a widget in streamSubscription.listen onData, which is void

Tags: flutter, dart, stream

I'm trying to return a widget in the streamSubscription.listen's onData callback. However, the `Text` widget in the example below never renders. I think this is because the onData method is of void type.

How do I return a widget in response to stream data?

```
@override 
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = geo
        .collection(collectionRef: ref)
        .within(center: center, radius: radius, field: field);
    stream.listen((List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList) {
      return Text('this text never renders');
    });
    return Text("loading");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return a `Widget` there.
You can use `setState()` instead, with a `bool` value.

For example:

1. Declare `bool isLoading` variable.
2. Change its value inside the stream listener like `setState(() => isLoading = true);`
3. Using the `isLoading`'s value, render your widget like:

```dart
Container(
  child: isLoading ? Text("loading") : Text('Not Loading, some Data here');
)
```

Alternatively, you can use a `ValueListenableBuilder` or better, a `StreamBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@override 
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> stream = geo
      .collection(collectionRef: ref)
      .within(center: center, radius: radius, field: field);
  return StreamBuilder(
    stream: stream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
        return Text("Loading...");
      }
      return Text('this text never renders');
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html), It will return Widget as you expect

```
 StreamBuilder<List<DocumentSnapshot>>(
      stream:
          geo.collection(collectionRef: ref).within(center: center, radius: radius, field: field),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text("loading");
        } else {
          return Text('this text never renders');
        }
      },
    );
```